# Sending whats app message through Microsoft.XmlHttp not working on windows 7 for vb6

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to send WhatsApp message using vb6, it works well on windows 10 but on windows 7 it through's an error on calling myMSXML.send strFormData, and the error is blank. i'm not understanding why it is giving error.

i have given the code below

```
    Private Function PrepareAndSendMsg(Partyname As String, Number As String, Optional Message As String = "", Optional Document As String = "") As Boolean
On Error GoTo X
'Whats app Variables --------------------------
Dim apikey As String
Dim ApiToken As String
Dim strFormData As String
Dim strUrl As String
Dim filepathname As String
Dim myMSXML As Object
'----------------------------------------------

strUrl = Trim(GetDescription("SELECT ISNULL(URL,'') FROM WHATSAPPDATA"))
apikey = Trim(GetDescription("SELECT ISNULL(API,'') FROM WHATSAPPDATA"))
ApiToken = Trim(GetDescription("SELECT ISNULL(TOKEN,'') FROM WHATSAPPDATA"))
'filepathname = Trim(GetDescription("SELECT ISNULL(FILEPATH,'') FROM WHATSAPPDATA")) 'no need generated evrytime

If dataValidate(strUrl, apikey, ApiToken, filepathname, Partyname, Number) = False Then: PrepareAndSendMsg = False: Call writeLog("DATA VALIDATION : User Data Validation Falied", "Y"): Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(App.Path & "\images\Error.ico"): Exit Function
writeLog ("DATA VALIDATION : User Data Validation Successfull")
If Message <> "" Then
    writeLog ("TYPE : Sending User ""MESSAGE""")
    strFormData = "key=" & apikey & "&token=" & ApiToken & "&number=" & Number & "&message=" & Message & "&type=text"
ElseIf Document <> "" Then
    writeLog ("TYPE : Sending User ""DOCUMENT""")
    strFormData = "key=" & apikey & "&token=" & ApiToken & "&number=" & Number & "&filepath=" & Document & "&type=file"
Else
    Call writeLog("Attchment or Message Not Found", "Y")
    LbPartyName.Caption = "Message/Attachment Not Found"
    PrepareAndSendMsg = False
    Exit Function
End If
writeLog ("KEY : " & apikey)
writeLog ("TOKEN : " & ApiToken)
writeLog ("API : " & strFormData)
Set myMSXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")
myMSXML.open "POST", "" & strUrl & "", False
myMSXML.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
myMSXML.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Firefox 3.6.4"
myMSXML.send strFormData
TxtRepsonse.Text = myMSXML.responseText
'Print Log and Close Here --------------
writeLog ("RESPONSE : " & TxtRepsonse.Text)
Call writeLog("", "Y")
'---------------------------------------
Timer11.Enabled = True
Exit Function
X:
    writeLog ("ERROR : Preparin And Sending Message ->" & Err.Description)
    PrepareAndSendMsg = False
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Warning"
End Function
```

as i mentioned error is blank and the same works well on windows 10. The Api provider is mentioned it has to compulsorily use POST method GET cannot be used.

Comment: Possibly the MSXML DLL you are using is not installer or registered properly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have checked it and re-registered the dll and I have tried it in multiple PC's.. every pc with windows 7 has the same problem

Comment: Err number is -2147467259

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Set myMSXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP").

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).